# Bigdecimal throws exception

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I've wrote this little piece of code:

```
BigDecimal nummer = new BigDecimal("8340337220.0");
BigDecimal denominator = new BigDecimal("17.O");
BigDecimal result = nummer.divide(denominator);
System.out.println(result);
```

After running it in eclipse it gives me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:459)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:728)
    at main.main(main.java:10)
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you have a capital letter "O" in `"17.O"`.  Replace with a zero:

```
BigDecimal denominator = new BigDecimal("17.0");
```

Comment: Thanks, my bad. Now I get this:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.

Comment: BigDecimals are arbitrary precision, but not infinite precision.  You'll need to use the `divide` method that takes an integer scale and a `RoundingMode`.

Answer (score 0):

```
BigDecimal nummer = new BigDecimal("83227720.0");
BigDecimal denominator = new BigDecimal("17.0");
BigDecimal result = nummer.divide(denominator,10,RoundingMode.DOWN);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Mere code doesn't answer the question. What was the problem you identified?